# Defining custom Mono "using" directive like for Java "import"

Tags: c#, java, mono

To avoid repetitive definitions, I am trying to move `internal function prototypes` from the class `One` into a C# `using My.Class.One` directive (like `import My.Class.One` in Java).

In Java, this would change this code:

```
public class One {
   public static void func1();
   public static void func2();
   public static int main(String[] args) { ... }
}
```

...into that code split into different files:

```
import My.Include;

public class One {
   public static int Main(String[] args) { ... }
}
------------------------->8--------------------------------    
package Include;

public class My {
   public static void func1();
   public static void func2();
   ...
}
```

After learning that Java `'packages'` are named `'namespaces'` in C# I came up with the following C# code which fails to compile (`mcs One.cs My_include.cs -out:One.exe`) with the error:

**> "error CS0103: The name `func1' does not exist in the current context"**

```
using System;
using My.Include;

public class One {
   public static int Main(String[] args) { return funct1(); }
}
------------------------->8--------------------------------    
using System;

namespace My {
   namespace Include {
      public class functions {
      public static void func1();
      public static void func2();
      ...
      }
   }
}
```

---

I tried many different naming conventions but I still get the same error. Can you tell me what I do wrong?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're doing here, or what the Java code would look like.

Comment: As written in the question above, the Java code would substitute the C# "using" by using the Java "import" to avoid repetitive declarations.

Comment: But that doesn't make sense, as you're *declaring* the class `One` *and trying to import it at the same time* in the second snippet. Again, that would make no sense in Java. If you could show a *full* Java example, it would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want a `partial class`, so your main class file would look like:

```
// File:  One.cs
using System;

public class One
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Your Main method here
    }
}
```

And you would have a second file which looks like:

```
// File:  One.Externs.cs
using System;

public partial class One
{
    extern static void func1();
    extern static void func2();
}
```

At compile-time, these two (or more) files are automatically combined to a single class by the compiler.  This gives you the separation you appear to be looking for, but keeps the relevant definitions within the correct scopes.

The `using` directive is only partially synonymous to java's `import` directive - in C# `using` only provides a shortcut into a `namespace` whereas you're used to referring to a class or partial class with `import`.

Comment: Thank you Mike, your suggestion is even cleaner than the model I used with Java!

Comment: Mike, What if I need to include this "partial Class" for other C# Classes?

Comment: The `partial` keyword is used to split a single class into multiple sources.  If you need the same `extern` definitions in multiple places within your code, you might be better to define a `public static class` which contains all of your `extern`s, and reference that class wherever you need to make the call to the unmanaged code.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Would this public static class need to be referenced in the source code like with the Java "import My.Include;
" directive? (see updated question above) Or would the mcs compiler just find what it needs if all classes are given on the same command-line?

Comment: If the classes are all provided on the same command line, the compiler will build them.  If the class is in a different `namespace` then for convenience you might wish to add a `using` directive at the head of other files.  The thing to remember is that `using` just tells the compiler which namespaces to look in for object definitions, which is subtly different from the `import` directive in java.